# Wireframe shading issue in Blender 2.91 viewer

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, shaders, wireframe

I'm new to Blender and I've been trying to get the wireframe shading to work since 2 days and been having this issue shown in the image below:

[image]

Whenever I try to go into wireframe shading mode it makes the object transparent.
Things I have tried:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling Blender.
2. Loading factory settings.
3. Turning on wireframe in overlay drop-down.
4. Selecting wireframe in viewport display under object properties.

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated.

Comment: AMD graphics card? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203615/how-to-fix-material-and-render-previews#comment342453_203615

Comment: if it is not your graphic card...please provide your .blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the viewport shading options while in wireframe and check x-ray. You probably have it disabled.[image: Shading options]